# How to get an attribute of an element in a javascript function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, reactjs

I have the following `<div>`:

```
<div
    data-target={`#ChooseAmount-${denomination.price}`}
    id="expandWhatsIncluded"
    className={this.state.isShowMore ?
    'ChooseAmount' : 'ChooseAmount-collapsed'}
    data-toggle="collapse"
    data-parent="#"
    aria-expanded="true"
    onClick={() => this.showMoreActive()}
>
```

And in the function `showMoreActive()`. I want to get the value of attribute `aria-expanded`.

I tried with the below code but got an error:

> object is possibly 'null'.ts(2531)

```
showMoreActive() {
    if (document.getElementById('expandWhatsIncluded') !== null) {
        const isExpanded = document.getElementById('expandWhatsIncluded').getAttribute("aria-expanded"); <!-- error is here -->
    }
}
```

Comment: TypeScript is telling you that `document.getElementById('expandWhatsIncluded')` might return `null`.

Comment: @Andreas Is there any way to bypass this?
I have used a property ` "strictNullChecks": true ` in my config file but setting it to ` false ` also gave the same error.

Comment: Would `this.state.isShowMore` be different value than `aria-expanded`? Because it looks like you may just be able to check that.

Comment: @AlexWayne The values are different.

Answer (score 0):

two minor problems, declare function with key word function and call the function correctly

```js
function showMoreActive() {
    if (document.getElementById('expandWhatsIncluded') !== null) {
        const isExpanded = document.getElementById('expandWhatsIncluded').getAttribute("aria-expanded");
        alert(isExpanded);
    }
}
```

```html
<div
    data-target={`#ChooseAmount-${denomination.price}`}
    id="expandWhatsIncluded"
    className={this.state.isShowMore ?
    'ChooseAmount' : 'ChooseAmount-collapsed'
    data-toggle="collapse"
    data-parent="#"
    aria-expanded=true
    onClick='showMoreActive()'
>xxx</div>
```

Comment: This is tagged with react where `onClick={() => {}}` is perfectly valid syntax. And `showMoreActive` is most likely a method in a class, where _that_ syntax is valid.

Answer (score 0):

Add the `return` keyword

```
function showMoreActive() {
      if (document.getElementById("expandWhatsIncluded") !== null) {
        const isExpanded = document
          .getElementById("expandWhatsIncluded")
          .getAttribute("aria-expanded");
          alert(isExpanded);
      }
    }
```

Comment: `alert()` doesn't return anything. Why should OP return that "nothing"/`undefined`?

Comment: Your answer is now meaningless because it's just the code from OP with a comment/change that doesn't explain why it should be used...